# Sending json Post date in android with parameter

Tags: java, android, post

I'm trying to make a POST request with Android, but I'm not succeeding. I think the problem is in how to set the parameters for resquisição and Header. Below is my method I do the request ...

```
public void testPostDate() {

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 10000);
    HttpResponse response;

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    CrimePOST.Crime crime = new CrimePOST().new Crime(10, "São Paulo",
            "descrição", 10.00, 30.00);

    CrimePOST crimePost = new CrimePOST();
    crimePost.setCrime(crime);

    List<NameValuePair> params = new LinkedList<NameValuePair>();

    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("token",
            "0V1AYFK12SeCZHYgXbNMew==$tRqPNplipDwtbD0vxWv6GPJIT6Yk5abwca3IJa6JhMs="));

    String json = gson.toJson(crimePost);

    String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, Utils.ENCODE);

    try {
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(
                "http://safe-sea-4024.herokuapp.com/crimes/mobilecreate"
                        + "?" + paramString);

        post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

        StringEntity entitty = new StringEntity(json);
        entitty.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,
                "application/json"));

        post.setEntity(entitty);
        response = client.execute(post);

        /* Checking response */
        if (response != null) {
            InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
            String a = toString(in);
            System.out.println(a);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

This method is responsible for converting an inputStream to String

```
    private String toString(InputStream is) throws IOException {

    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int lidos;
    while ((lidos = is.read(bytes)) > 0) {
        baos.write(bytes, 0, lidos);
    }
    return new String(baos.toByteArray());
}
```

Really I am passing the Header correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do this in an AsyncTask

Comment: This is a test method therefore does not need a AsyncTask.

Comment: That's an important information. I don't know how unit tests work in android. But what is the error message?

Comment: I connect successfully. However, my server returns an error telling me that it takes a set a Content Headers. I'm probably going the wrong way Content Headers: (

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this tutorial while back. it does send json data via HTTP Post to a url. Check it out. Original post can be found here:http://androidhappenings.blogspot.com/2013/03/android-app-development-201-1st.html

```
    import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener{
private TextView textView =null;
LocationManager locationManager=null;
Location location=null;
protected String url;
protected JSONObject jsonData=null;
private EditText urlText=null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    final boolean gpsEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if(gpsEnabled!=true) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GPS Disbled! Please Enable to Proceed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
    } 

    textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 1, this);
    urlText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.urlTextbox);
    Button submitButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submitUrl);

    submitButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (urlText.getText()!=null) {
            url=urlText.getText().toString();
            System.out.println(url);//for testing only, not required
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Url Submitted, Sending data to Web Service at url: " + url, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        }
    });




}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
    this.location=location;
     final Handler handler = new Handler();
      Timer ourtimer = new Timer();
      TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
          int cnt=1;    
          public void run() {
                      handler.post(new Runnable() {
                              public void run() {

                                Double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                Double longitude = location.getLongitude();
                                Double altitude = location.getAltitude();
                                Float accuracy = location.getAccuracy();
                                textView.setText("Latitude: " + latitude + "\n" + "Longitude: " + longitude+ "\n" + "Altitude: " + altitude + "\n" + "Accuracy: " + accuracy + "meters"+"\n" + "Location Counter: " + cnt);
                            try {
                                jsonData = new JSONObject();
                                jsonData.put("Latitude", latitude);
                                jsonData.put("Longitude", longitude);
                                jsonData.put("Altitude", altitude);
                                jsonData.put("Accuracy", accuracy);

                                System.out.println(jsonData.toString());//not required, for testing only
                                if(url!=null) {
                                new HttpPostHandler().execute();
                                }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                                cnt++;
                              }

                     });
              }};
          ourtimer.schedule(timerTask, 0, 120000);

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {


}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {


}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {


}





public class HttpPostHandler extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

     HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
     HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
     StringEntity dataEntity = null;
    try {
        dataEntity = new StringEntity(jsonData.toString());
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     httpPost.setEntity(dataEntity);
     httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    try {
        httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    return null;


}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    try {
        this.finalize();
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}

}
```